# Build ios .ipa using jenkins and fastlane (host ubuntu)

Tags: ios, ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, fastlane

any idea if it is possible to generate .ipa (ios app ) with jenkins installed on ubuntu machine.
If it is a NO (and i think its) 
any other solution guys 
i saw travis but it doesn't support bitbucket 
I tried circleCi but you need to pay if you want a suuport for ios

Comment: Install Jenkins agent on Mac PC and connect that agent to main Jenkins server. This will help to build ios app from Jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the only solution i find it  is to use the distributed arch of jenkins , that means  :
I will install a Jenkins master on my Ubuntu machine and another slave node on a mac machine and give it the access so i can build my own ipa every time there is triggers on my repo.

Comment: Yes the issue is that iOS is only available on the MacOS operating system. A common practice for small setups is to have a mac mini always connected to the internet and that acts as a jenkins slave, as you mentioned you can also use CircleCI